# Изменение цвета табов в браузере

Tags: javascript, html, css, chrome-extension, firefox-extension

Доброго времени суток,

Хотел бы написать дополнение для браузера, которое будет менять цвет таба исходя из позиции его расположения по нумерации, однако не знаю как выделить отдельный таб и дать ему определенное цветовое значение.

Как это должно выглядеть в моем понимании :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже разбирался с апи, но нашел только изменение темы цветовой для всего браузера, либо же для активной вкладки, однако интересуют исключительно перекрашивание табов.

Желательно браузер firefox, однако подойдет и все что на хромиуме.

Большое спасибо всем ответившим

Comment: В хроме точно нельзя, нашёл на реддите прошлогодний ответ от одного из разрабов. Для firefox не знаю, но тоже вряд ли. В основном только всю тему перекрашивают.

Comment: хм...я нашел flrefox приложение, которое может отображать подчеркивания на вкладках, при создании новой группы ей присваивается цвет. Как я понимаю это может работать через выделение активной вкладки и присваивание ей некоторых стилей? Приложение Multy-accounts container [скрин](https://b.radikal.ru/b22/2005/72/e1c66e7e5edf.png)

Answer (score 0):

для файрфокса уже есть аддон Colorful Tabs, который делает именно это. Может, можно скачать и посмотреть, как именно?

[ссылка на страницу аддона на официальном сайте](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorfultabs/)

Comment: Скачал этот плагин, он имеет странный функционал. Перекрашивает темы страниц полностью, а не только табов и в добавок к этому создает свой сайд бар [вот демонстрация](https://a.radikal.ru/a09/2005/a1/92e95011abcf.png)

Comment: ну, сайдбар можно выключить. 
вскройте плагин и посмотрите, что он дергает.

Comment: он меняет темы для каждой страницы, это я умею делать, а вот перекрашивать отдельно табы он не умеет.... и картинка на превью это либо старая очень версия плагина, либо обман. Так как сейчас подобного функционала просто нет в нем